# Problems with using accumulate in c++

Tags: c++, accumulate

I'm using OpenCV to access the color data of the pixels within a specified area and currently I'm trying to use the accumulate method in c++ to sum up all the data numbers obtained in that specified area. But right now it has only given me the sum of only a single pixel within the specified area and not the whole area. I'm sure it is giving me the sum of a single pixel because I have used the push_back method and it has given me double the amount in that pixel. Is there something that I have missed and have not written? I'm kind of new to c++ so I would appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction.

```
    //the rows of the image
    for(int j=0; j<image; j++){
      int step = j*cols*elemSize;
      //the columns for the image
      for(int i-0; i<image; i++){
        int elm = i*elemSize;
        //obtaining the color data of the pixels
        uchar blue = image.data[step + elm + 0];
        uchar green = image.data[step + elm + 1];
        uchar red = image.data[step + elm + 2];
        std::vector<int> v = {blue};
        std::vector<int> w = {green};
        std::vector<int> x = {red};
        //using accumulate to sum up all the data
        int sumofblue = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
        int sumofgreen = accumulate(w.begin(), w.end(), 0);
        int sumofred = accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0);
```

The blue green red is the color data extracted(0-255) from the specified area and image.data is defined as the image used in the extraction.

Comment: What is `blue`, `green`, and `red`? Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And when you say that you only get result for a single "pixel", it's because your vectors only contains one element each. Perhaps you redefine the vectors `v`, `w` and `x` inside a loop, when you really should be pushing back into other vectors defined outside the loop, and then do the accumulate calls after the loop?

Comment: `std::vector<int> v = {blue};` is a vector constisting of a single element taken from `image.data[step + elm + 0];`. Perhaps you wanted to copy more elements from `image.data` to the vector, but you don't do that. Note that you do not need to copy to a vector to use the algorithm. `std::accumulate` can also use pointers to a c-array

Comment: `j<image` and `i<image` ?!? Is this the real code? What is `image` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Considering that, and the `int i-0`, I doubt it's a proper [mre].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude definitely not a mre, and considering that, also the code that has been posted seems to be modifed such that it is almost impossible to help :/

Comment: look at the contents of the vector. You will see that `std::accumulate` is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something that I have missed and have not written?

you've missed the fact that you are still in the middle of your loop. You need to define `v`, `w` and `x` before the loop, and add each element, then accumulate after the loop.

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int> w;
std::vector<int> x;
//the rows of the image
for(int j=0; j<image/*??*/; j++){
  int step = j*cols*elemSize;
  //the columns for the image
  for(int i-0; i<image/*??*/; i++){
    int elm = i*elemSize;
    //obtaining the color data of the pixels
    v.push_back(image.data[step + elm + 0]);
    w.push_back(image.data[step + elm + 1]);
    x.push_back(image.data[step + elm + 2]);
  }
}

//using accumulate to sum up all the data
int sumofblue = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
int sumofgreen = accumulate(w.begin(), w.end(), 0);
int sumofred = accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0);
```

However you might as well just use `+=` in the loop

```
int sumofblue = 0;
int sumofgreen = 0;
int sumofred = 0;
//the rows of the image
for(int j=0; j<image/*??*/; j++){
  int step = j*cols*elemSize;
  //the columns for the image
  for(int i-0; i<image/*??*/; i++){
    int elm = i*elemSize;
    //obtaining the color data of the pixels
    sumofblue += image.data[step + elm + 0];
    sumofgreen += image.data[step + elm + 1];
    sumofred += image.data[step + elm + 2];
  }
}
```

If you have access to a [ranges library with stride and drop](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#autotoc_md8), you don't need the nested loop at all. Depending on exactly what `image.data` is, you may need to wrap it in a `std::span`

```
std::span data { image.data, image.data_size }; // cols * rows * elemSize?
auto blue = data | views::stride(3);
auto green = data | views::drop(1) | views::stride(3);
auto red = data | views::drop(2)  | views::stride(3);
int sumofblue = std::accumulate(begin(blue), end(blue), 0);
int sumofgreen = std::accumulate(begin(green), end(green), 0);
int sumofred = std::accumulate(begin(red), end(red), 0);
```

Comment: I am reasonably sure that `data` is `uint8_t*` or similar.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yeah, probably

Comment: @Caleth Thank you very much. Defining the v w x before the loop solved the problem.